# Get height of DIV and its content with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height

I have a div which contains several elements:

```
<div class="menuItem designMenu" id="dMenu">
  <ul class="menuList menu">
    <li class="menuHeader">Design</li>
    <li class="projectHeader">Mother</li>
    <li class="projectBody">Some text here</li>
    <li class="more">More</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I need to get the height of the dMenu items that I can animate it upwards, including all the content inside.  My Javascript currently:

```
var designHeight = $("#dMenu").height();
```

Returns nothing.

I've tried `offsetHeight`, `scrollHeight`, and everything else Google turns up.  I'm running the jQuery at the end of the body, inside a document ready function.

The reason to get the height to animate, instead of doing it manually, is that a: I'd like to learn how and b: I don't yet know how many items will be in the div.

Comment: Does it actually have a height, did you set a height? Try setting a background color or overflow to hidden, and see if the element your trying to get the height of has a height, or if it's just the other elements overflowing.

Comment: What you've posted works or *should* work, unless there's some special consideration that you've not mentioned (such as `display: none`, or something); have you checked for typos or syntax errors?

Comment: The code you have that uses `.height()` works just fine when implemented properly.  You can see that here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wxvNs/.  So, there's something else going on in your page that you are not disclosing to us.  For example, do you have jQuery loaded into the page?

Comment: did you load jQuery before your script? does jQuery even load? did you wrap your functions in `.ready()`? what does the console say?

Comment: Hello.  I don't think I was missing anything with regards to info for the question.  JQuery, Java etc are all loaded etc.  I have it working kind of with "var codeHeight = $("#cMenu")[0].scrollHeight;" however I have to manually remove an arbitrary amount, in this case 75 pixels, to get the correct height.  I'll clean up and post my entire DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the `li`s within the `ul` floated? If so, and the parent does not have `overflow: hidden` the parent collapses and therefor has no height. Try (if possible) adding  `overflow: hidden` to the parent element, or hard code a height in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using scrollHeight to get at what I want.  I also, embarrassingly, noticed as I was fiddling with things I was loading my JS before loading JQuery.  So ashamed I didn't spot that.